# By direct computation, check that the function u(x) = $|x|^{1/2}$ cos($\theta$/2) is harmonic in the upper half plane H := {x = (x1, x2) | x2 > 0}.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

Okay so Partial Differential Equations make no sense to me. Don't know what to do. All I know is that if a function u is harmonic then $\Delta$u = 0

Comment: One way to look at this would be to write $u(z)=\text{Re}(\sqrt{z})$ in $H$. Since the last is an holomorphic function we get that $u$is harmonic.

Comment: Sorry, just noticed the "by direct computation". In this case write the laplacian in polar coordinates and just take the appropriate partial derivatives. This is no PDE problem really, just advanced calculus.